# conditional probability calculation confusion

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

Suppose I have 3 friends, each of them are independent and each of them have the probability of p to tell the truth about something (e.g. company, weather, stock, etc.).

Suppose something happened (e.g. company is holding a party other than not holding a party, weather is good other than bad, stock is rising other than drop, etc.), 
I want to calculate what is the probability 2 of them telling truth, and 1 of them telling wrong?

I think the answer is `3*p*p*(1-p)`, correct?

But what is the probability of something is true, if 2 of the friends telling me truth, but 1 of friends telling me it is not truth?

```
P (true | T, T, F) = P (T,T,F|true) * P(true) / P(T,T,F)
demominator P (T,T,F) = P(true) * P(T,T,F|true) + P(false) * P (T,T,F|false)
Suppose prior P(true) = 1/2 and P(false) = 1-1/2 = 1/2, then it become
P (T,T,F) = x*3*p*p*1/2 + 1/2*3*p*(1-p)*(1-p)
numerator = x*3*p*p*(1-p)1/2
final result = p
```

Suppose I consult more friends, but still they have the same ratio telling the true or not, so for 6 friends, 4 of them telling truth and 2 of them telling false
The result becomes,

```
P (true | T,T,T,T,F,F) = P (T,T,T,T,F,F|true) * P(true) / P(T,T,T,T,F,F)
numerator = C(2,6)*1/2*p^4*(1-p)^2
demominator = C(2,6)*1/2*p^4*(1-p)^2 + C(2,6)*1/2*p^2*(1-p)^4
C(2,6) means select 2 from 6, which is 15
final result is p^2 / (p^2 + (1-p)^2)
```

If I want to compare if asking 3 friends has higher probability of truth, or asking 6 friends, I just need to compare between p and p^2 / (p^2 + (1-p)^2),

I did calcualation, which gets as long as (2p-1)*(p-1) > 0, asking more friends, is better, which result in p<1/2, it seems counter intuitive?

My intuitive is, asking more friends is better if any individual friend has high confidence (p>1/2)? Anything wrong in my calculation?

Comment: This question seems reasonable to me. I am not sure who down-voted it, but it would be helpful if you could give a reason? (+1 to counter-act down vote)

Comment: Thanks for the support @GeoMatt22, if you have any comments to my original question, it will be great. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 4 of 6 case to be better than the 2 of 3 case,

$\frac{p^2}{p^2+(1-p)^2}>p$

$p^2>p^3+p\cdot(1-p)^2$

$p>p^2+(1-p)^2\space\space\space\space\space\space\space, p>0$

$0>p^2+(1-p)^2-p$

$0>p^2+1-2p+p^2-p$

$0>(2p-1)\cdot (p-1)\space\space\space$,I think you have the product as > 0

for p < 1, divide by the negative quantity (p-1), meaning the inequality must reverse

$0 < 2p-1$

$p>\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks MikeP, you rock! Now there is no counter intuitive -- more people I asked, more confidence I have. Do you think prior matters (to make the conclusion if asking more people is better, even if people give yes/no answer with the same ratio)? For prior, I mean probability of good weather, probability of stock rise, etc.

Comment: BTW, Mike, for my first question in the post, I want to calculate what is the probability 2 of them telling truth, and 1 of them telling wrong?

I think the answer is `3*p*p*(1-p)`, correct?

Comment: Yes I agree! 3*p*p*(1-p).  Regarding the priors, let me do some algebra and get back to you :)

Comment: So, in short, yes the a priori probability matters, as usual.  For example, instead of just p for P(2T1F) it becomes p P(t) / ( 2 p P(t) - p - P(t) - 1).  And P(4T2F) is even worse.  I then divided them, but could not reduce it to something nice.  I got the increase to be p*(P(t) (2p-1) + p (1-p))/(P(t) (2p-1) + (1-p)^2).  Yuck.

Comment: Thanks MikeP, I thought maybe we can write a function to plot some results. Do you know if pandas/numpy/scikit-learn have any function to calculate the combinations? For example, select 2 out of 6 is 15?

Comment: Nope, sorry I haven't used any of those

Comment: Thanks for all the help MikeP, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you're saying, because of your English and terminology, but it sounds like you're supposing you have $n$ independent binary signals of a single binary event, each of which has probability $p$ of being correct, and you want to compute the probability that the event actually happened. This is equivalent to supposing you have $n$ independent draws from a Bernoulli distribution whose parameter $θ$ is either $p$ or $1 - p$, and you want to estimate $θ$. This formulation makes it obvious what's missing from your scenario: a prior distribution for $θ$. Although we know $θ$ can only have one of two possible values, we need to decide on their relative prior probability in order to get a posterior estimate for $θ$.

So, choose a prior. Let $α ∈ [0, 1]$ such that a priori, $θ$ has probability $α$ to be $p$ and probability $1 - α$ to be $1 - p$. Given the $n$ Bernoulli trials, let $k$ be the observed number of successes. Then by Bayes's theorem,

$$\begin{align*}
&\phantom{=} P(θ = p | X = x) \\
&= \frac{P(X = x | θ = p) P(θ = p)}{P(X = x)} \\
&= \frac{p^k(1 - p)^{n - k} α}
   {(αp + (1 - α)(1 - p))^k (α(1 - p) + (1 - α)p)^{n - k}}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks Kodiologist for the reply, vote up. Wondering what means `X` in your formula? We can use stock rise/drop as an example, suppose each friend has 2/3 probability to tell the truth, which is P(a friend tell stock rise|stock rise) = 2/3, P(a friend tell stock drop|stock rise) = 1/3, and P(a friend tell stock drop|stock drop) = 2/3 and P(a friend tell stock rise|stock drop) = 1/3.

Comment: BTW Kodiologist, I like the way you model output from friend as a Bernoulli distribution, which has two outputs. But I am a bit doubt, since Bernoulli distribution also needs to output two possible output with fixed probability (please feel free to correct me). But in my case, let us use stock rise as an example, friend will output rise (with 2/3 probability) drop (with 1/3 probability) if stock rise, and friend will output drop (with 2/3 probability) rise (with 1/3 probability) if stock drop.

Comment: (cont'd) as you can see, even if there are only two possible output from each friend, but the probability of the output of two possible outcome are different under different condition, this is my point, I am not sure if we can model such as unconditional Bernoulli distribution? I would say under a specific random event (stock rise or stock drop), the outcome from a friend under a Bernoulli distribution, and under different random event  (stock rise or stock drop), the distribution is different. Please feel free to correct me if I am reading anything wrong from your descriptions.

Comment: @LinMa $X$ just means the data and $x$ its observed value. "as you can see, even if there are only two possible output from each friend, but the probability of the output of two possible outcome are different under different condition" — Yes, and those two different possible states of the world are captured in the model I described by the two possible values of $θ$.

Comment: Thanks Kodiologist, I read your reply again and I think for $\theta$ you mean the probability of p to tell the truth? If so, `p` is known to us. My purpose is I want to calculate kinds of election results (similar to random forest), for example, whether I am more confident stock will rise, if 4 of 6 are telling me stock will rise, comparing to 2 of 3 (keep the same ratio) telling me stock will rise. So, no need to estimate `p` (or in your words $\theta$)? Did I mis-understand anything, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: "for $θ$ you mean the probability of $p$ to tell the truth?" — No, $θ$ is the probability of each person saying "yes", so it equals $p$ if the correct answer is "yes" and $1 - p$ if the correct answer is "no".

Comment: Thanks Kodiologist, for part of your formula, $P(θ=p|X=x)$, I think `x` is a random event for the truth about what happened, for example `X=stock rise`, `p` is some probability we know, for example, `p=2/3`, which means `2/3` probability friend tell us stock rise if `X=stock rise`, `1/3` probability friend tell us stock drop if `X=stock rise` -- similar to, which also means `2/3` probability friend tell us stock drop if `X=stock drop`, `1/3` probability friend tell us stock rise if `X=stock drop`.

Comment: (cont'd) what I want to calculate is, `P(X=stock rise | friend 1 tells me stock rise, friend 2 tells me stock rise and friend 3 tells me stock drop)`. In this representation, I do not see any need to introduce $\theta$ to add another level of complexity. Maybe I mis-read something from your points? From my above description, what is $\theta$? For your comments, you are calculating the probability of someone say yes, but what I need is what is the probability of something truly happened, if I consult some friends, which could be represented as,

Comment: (cont'd) `P(X=stock rise | friend 1 tells me stock rise, friend 2 tells me stock rise and friend 3 tells me stock drop)`, so it sounds to me, we are talking about something different, and it might be my issue not stating the question super clear. :)

Comment: @LinMa "I think x is a random event for the truth about what happened, for example `X=stock rise`" — No, $X$ is the random vector representing your friends' statements (1 for "yes", 0 for "no"). "what I want to calculate is…" — Then calculate $P(θ = p | X = x)$, as above. That's the probability the event actually happened, which is what you want. Like I said, $θ$ is $p$ if the correct answer is "yes" (the event happened) and $1 - p$ if the correct answer is "no" (the event didn't happen).

Comment: "I do not see any need to introduce $θ$ to add another level of complexity." — If you can figure out how to solve this problem without a random variable representing whether the event actually happened, be my guest.

Comment: Thanks Kodiologist. I think conditional probability means, under some random event, what is the probability of some other random event. In my example, I want to calculate what is the probability of stock rise (a random event), under the condition of 2 of 3 analyst said stock will rise (another random event). For what `X` is for, totally agree with you (let us say X means 2 of 3 analyst said stock will rise). What I feel confused is, I think I want to calculate $P(stock truly rise | X)$, **not** the probability of stock rise is 2/3 (or 1/3), under the condition of `X`.

Comment: (cont'd) for your comments "That's the probability the event actually happened, which is what you want", yes, I agree. But if you are using $\theta$ to represent for a random event of something truly happened, its probability could be **any value**, based on how many analyst I asked, and also what probability each individual analyst predict truth (which is `p`). Vote up for your both reply and if I mis-read any of your comments, please feel free to correct me. :)

Comment: BTW, if you read the formula written by MikeP, the probability of stock truly rise, under the condition about M of N independent analyst said stock will rise, could be any values.

Comment: @LinMa I don't know what to tell you. Good luck.

Comment: Appreciate all of your help, Kodiologist.